# Bypass IAsyncAuthorizationFilter filter

Tags: asp.net-core

```
  public class AuthenticationFilter : IAsyncAuthorizationFilter
{
    public async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        var authToken = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("Authorization");
        if (!authToken)
        {
            context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
        }
    }
}
```

This filter is being called before every controller, i want to skip this filter for login and register user controller. How to do this in Asp.net Core, I tried adding AllowAnonymous decorator it didnt work.

In startup.cs

```
services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
        {
            //TODO: remove in production.
            options.Filters.Add(new CorsAuthorizationFilterFactory("AllowSpecificOrigin"));
            options.Filters.Add(new AuthenticationFilter());
        });
```

Comment: Can you show how you added `AllowAnonymous`? That should have worked.

Comment: [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous] 
        public async Task<ActionResult<object>> Post([FromBody] User user)
        {}. Then i added the following in the AuthenticationFilter it helped me to skip the action..         if(context.ActionDescriptor is ControllerActionDescriptor descriptor)
            {
                var attributes = descriptor.MethodInfo.CustomAttributes;
                if (attributes.Any(a => a.AttributeType == typeof(AllowAnonymous)))
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
           Is it right way to do?

Comment: it would be helpful if you could update your question with all the details.